# How to create JSON dynamically using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I'm forming JSON inside my forEach loop based on certain conditions but JSON is not forming the way I expected, please find my code below:

**app.js**

```
var myObject = {
    product: [
        {
            timestamp: 1622650177246,
            message: 'productID-123839'
        },
        {
            timestamp: 1622650177268,
            message: 'productName-iPhone'
        }
    ]
}

var jsonArr = [];

myObject.product.forEach(function (data) {
    //console.log(myObject)
    console.log(data.message)

    if (data.message.includes('123839')) {
        jsonArr.push({ 'productID': data.message })
    }
    if (data.message.includes('iPhone')) {
        jsonArr.push({ 'productName': data.message })
    }


});

console.log(jsonArr)
```

I'm getting output like this:

```
[
  { productID: 'productID-123839' },
  { productName: 'productName-iPhone' }
]
```

But my expected output something like this:

```
{ 
productID: 'productID-123839',
productName: 'productName-iPhone' 
}
```

And finally, I would like to read `jsonArr.productID` or `jsonArr.productName`

How to get something like this, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected output is an object, not an array. If you want that output, your code should be like this:

```
var jsonObj = {};

myObject.product.forEach(function (data) {
    //console.log(myObject)
    console.log(data.message)

    if (data.message.includes('123839')) {
        jsonObj.productID = data.message;
    }
    if (data.message.includes('iPhone')) {
        jsonObj.productName = data.message;
    }


});

console.log(jsonObj);
```